# Load DATA into Stored Procedure (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm using MySQL , 
and trying to create stored procedure 
that get CSV file (with 2 columns - ID & Name)
,delete  table person_table and 
create it with the CSV content.

This is the code:

```
DELIMITER $$

drop procedure if exists load_persons$$

CREATE PROCEDURE load_persons(in file_name varchar(300))
BEGIN

     drop table if exists person_table;

    CREATE TABLE `person_table` (
      `ID` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `Name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file_name INTO TABLE person_table;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

unfortunately I get an error : 'LOAD DATA is not allowed in stored procedures'

what can I do ?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can call to `load` command after stored procedure:

```
CALL load_persons(...);
-- and then
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE your_file_name INTO TABLE person_table;
```

Comment: Hi thank you!
but i need it will execute into the SP.

Comment: There is no possible due to MySQL polices: "LOAD DATA is not allowed in stored procedures"

Comment: It's about security